# 'Xojo' is the only application that I can't install

Tags: 14.04, software-recommendation, software-center, software-installation

I can't install `xojo`. When I click install in the software center it's not progressing.
In the terminal it's stuck in :

```
gichan02@gichan02-Latitude-D520:~$ sudo apt-get install xojo
[sudo] password for gichan02: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
xojo-bin
The following NEW packages will be installed:
 xojo xojo-bin
0 upgraded, 2 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 209 MB/209 MB of archives.
After this operation, 596 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
0% [Working]
```

then after waiting for an hour for progress it says:

```
Failed to fetch https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xojo/xojo-bin_2013.41-0ubuntu1_i386.deb Could not resolve host: private-ppa.launchpad.net
```

So I added apt repository for 'private-ppa':

```
deb https://ging-giana:D69GwG16ZQKz2Rkb4C0Q@private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu trusty main
```

Then when I try 'apt-get update':

```
GPG error: https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release: The following signatures were invalid: NODATA 2
```

Then I noticed something the Software Sources:Other software TAB:

```
Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu
```

So i go to the '/etc/apt/auth.conf' ,but It cannot be opened and it is not a keyserver.
So i uncheck:

```
Added by software-center; credentials stored in /etc/apt/auth.conf
https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu
```

GPG error was gone.
But then again I found myself at the beginning of the problem.STUCK at '0% [Working]'.

'Xojo' is the only application that I can't install.Any explanation why is it like that?

Comment: Try from command line and see if it throws errors (if so: add them to your question by editing) (open a terminal and then `sudo apt-get install xojo`)

Comment: @Rinzwind terminal stack at "0% [Working]"

Comment: Are you behind a proxy server? If yes, have you added your proxy parameters in System settings-> Network -> Network Proxy?

Comment: @Jobin No.I connect directly.

Comment: Try `ping private-ppa.launchpad.net`

Comment: @bain It says
64 bytes from haetae.canonical.com (91.189.95.83): icmp_seq=75 ttl=48 time=355 ms
 What does it mean?

Comment: It means that the error `Could not resolve host: private-ppa.launchpad.net` should not happen. Are you sure you don't have a proxy configured? Try `apt-config dump|grep -i proxy`

Comment: @bain apt-config dump|grep -i proxy gives nothing..I still cannot install xojo.

Comment: Try `apt-get update; apt-get dist-upgrade; apt-get install xojo` Copy and paste any errors, exactly as they appear, into the question.

Comment: Try `apt-key adv --recv-keys --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com 00EF5DFB` then do the commands above.

Comment: It's because of the unemployment problem

Comment: @hakermania 'unemployment problem' ?What do you mean?

Comment: Are you on amd64? Apparently xojo does not support amd64 on Ubuntu 14.04 yet. Assuming you are on i386, you could just download the package yourself and install it: `wget https://private-ppa.launchpad.net/commercial-ppa-uploaders/xojo/ubuntu/pool/main/x/xojo/xojo-bin_2013.41-0ubuntu1_i386.deb; dpkg -i xojo-bin*.deb`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @bain.

I download .deb file in launhpad instead of downloading it in Software center or terminal.
I go to the 'My profile' then click ' View your private PPA subscriptions' so i can view the private PPA permission.Then click the link in the box and download the .deb file for ubuntu.